Looping problem when serializing objects to JSON in Spring Boot
I'm using Spring Boot 3.2 version with MySQL database. I have two objects
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "shops")
public class Shop{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String address;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Book> books;
}

and
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    private Shop shop;
}


So I have some lopping problem when I'm trying to get all Shops with all books. I have object Shop with all Books object inside each book has his own shop object inside with all book etc. And it looks like
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "address": "Street",
        "books": [
                {
                "id": 3,
                "description": "Book1",
                "shop" : {
                       "id": 4,
                       "address": "Street"
                       "books": [
                               {
                                "id": 3,
                                "description": "Book1",
                                "shop" : { ...
                               }
                       ]
                }
        ]
     }
]

So the problem is that I want to use one class for saving shops/books and geting from database.
Then I need that shop have all books as objects with all data but books have only shopId.
So getting all shops should look like this
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "address": "Street",
        "books": [
                {
                "id": 3,
                "description": "Book1",
                "shop" : 4
                }
         ]
     }
]

and geeting all books should look like this
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "description": "Book1",
        "shop": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "description": "Book2",
        "shop": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "description": "Book4",
        "shop": 5
    },
]

As I said I want to use same class for saving shop/books and same class for getting.
I faced with couple problems.

I dont want to create additional ShopDTO/BookDTO objects for getting because if it will be 1M books then I need to created 1M objects each time while getting.
I can't add just one more variable such as Long shopId; because it will be hibernate error
Table [books] contains physical column name [shop_id] referred to by multiple logical column names: [shop_id], [shopId]
I can't change

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
private Shop shop; 

on
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
private Long shop;

or remove @ManyToOne at all.

Isn't the books to shops relationship many-to-many (in the real world)?

For point 1 "objects for getting because if it will be 1M books then I need to created 1M objects" this will happen either way, if you have 1M books the call to books will create 1M objects (in the list). For 2 "I can't add just one more variable such as Long shopId;" yes you can, just annotate it with @Transient

@JimGarrison I think it is correct, a single instance (physical book) of a book can only be in one store?

OP, this might help you out: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

From the code it wasn't clear if "book" meant a book title or a physical book.  You'll be wasting a lot of space storing the same title over and over again. The book title should be stored once with its metadata (ISBN, etc) and book instances should refer to that table.

@JorgeCampos yes. i get all 1M objects but if I convert Book to BookDTO just to show shop_Id instead of shop I will get 2M objects instead of 1M. Is it make sense? I can add private transient Long shopId; but what is the sense?) It doesn't serialize and I don't get shopId while get all books

@JimGarrison it doesn't matteractually. In my project there are unique books and it can't be present in different shops so One to many is good for me

Sorry it doesn't make sense and no, you wouldn't be doubling the objects. Its either 1M for books or 1M for booksdto. I am not sure what is leading you to think it will double the objects.

@JorgeCampos I just found out that there is a solution to get all data from the database as a Shop class and then transform this to ShopDTO class but during the transformation getting only what I need to show in JSON

So I found the solution.
I have added @JsonIdentityInfo to my shop
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Shop{...

and added same for Book and added one more annotation to my Shop
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Book{...
   @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
   private Shop shop;
}


Glad that the article I shared was useful. :)

@Entity
@Table(name = "shops")
public class Shop {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String address;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    private Shop shop;

}


SELECT s.id, s.address, b.id AS bookId
FROM shops s
LEFT JOIN books b ON s.id = b.shop_id;


But there is no information in Shop about Books at all?
